# Chooser intent has no apps

Tags: java, android, android-intent, onclick

The problem I have is that when this intent is started there are no apps to show. Why is that? I need all apps to be visible since onClick the button will go to any app the user wants to and save it (use this app as default). What could be the solution?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_ALL_APPS);
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        String title = getResources().getString(R.string.chooser_title);
                        Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, title);
                        chooser.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        startActivity(chooser);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try-

```
Intent pickIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_ALL_APPS);
pickIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
pickIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(pickIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you all the apps in a list-

```
Intent pickIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
      pickIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
      List pkgAppsList = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( pickIntent, 0);
      Log.d(MainActivity.class.getSimpleName(), pkgAppsList.toString());
      //startActivity(pickIntent);
```

**pkgAppsList** will have the list of all the applications. Hope this solves your problem.